# import animation channels independently

Tags: python, import, keyframes

I wonder if I can import keyframes (with a python script) only as x keyframe. It seems like I can only set the whole object location at a keyframe, but I want only set the x location, since y location may have different keyframes. Is there any solution for this? 
I cant get it to work with object.insert_keyframe(data_path='location', frame = key.frame)

Otherwise I don't understand why the channels can be exported independently.
I already tried to import the specific x value by setting the current frames to the keyframe and use the objects frame location for y and z value.

Comment: Import from where? Do you mean append keyframes form a different blender file? Export independently to?

Answer (score 1):

Select the animated object, in the dopesheet select all keyframes you want to copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to copy in the clipboard, select the new object, select the channel to be animated, set the cursor to the first frame where you want the copied animation to start, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the single animation channel.

Answer (score 0):

To insert single keyframes select the object and type:

```
bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert('location', index=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the x-channel in the *3D Viewport's Right Side Property panel* and select *Insert Single Keyframe*.

[image]

Comment: Hi, of course i meant import with a python script (i should have pointed that out more clearly). So is there sth like obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='location_x', frame=key.frame)